# Symantec Messaging gateway add domain soap request

Tags: php, soap, symantec

I am trying to generate the following XML block in php to send it to SMG soap server. How can i do that?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dom="http://schemas.symantec.com/jaxws/domainProvisioningService">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <dom:AddDomains>
         <dom:domains>
            <domain name="domain1.com" local="true">               
            </domain>
             <domain name="domain2.com" local="true">               
            </domain>
         </dom:domains>
      </dom:AddDomains>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

So #1 I hate working with soap.  That said I would recommend using SoapClient (https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php).

You start off by instantiating a client and you pass in the wsdl like so:

```
$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('trace' => 1));
```

Whoever created the soap service will tell you where the wsdl is.

Now you can do something like:

```
$result = $client->AddDomains(
    array(
        array('name'=>'domain1.com', 'local'=>'true'), 
        array('name'=>'domain2.com', 'local'=>'true')
    )
);
```

But that might not work because the WSDL might require some specific wacky formatting or something. You need to check that the response isn't a soapfault

```
if (is_soap_fault($result)) {
    echo "REQUEST:\n" . $SOAP->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
    echo "SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$result->faultcode}, faultstring: {$result->faultstring}";
}
```

This should hopefully get you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but as you have said, it requires special formatting. i ran your code but it says no domain has been provided. specifically i need to construct this line of XML:
            <domain name="domain1.com" local="true">

Comment: I added the trace and an echo to show the last soap request xml that was sent, what is it sending?

Answer (score 0):

I executed the following php block and desired output created:

```
$xmldom = new DOMDocument(); 
$domainsAttr = $xmldom->createElement( "domains" );
$domainAttr = $xmldom->createElement( "domain" );
$domainAttr->setAttribute( "name", "test.com" );
$domainAttr->setAttribute( "local", "true" );
$domainsAttr->appendChild( $domainAttr );   
$xmldom->appendChild( $domainsAttr );
```

Here is desired output:

```
<domains><domain name="test.com" local="true"/></domains>
```

i omitted remaining code to post here, but when i execute the code, I get the following error:

```
Cannot find dispatch method for {}domains
```